# Remove adjacent duplicates given a condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm trying to write a function that will take a string, and given an integer, will remove all the adjacent duplicates larger than the integer and output the remaining string. I have this function right now that removes all the duplicates in a string, and I'm not sure how to put the integer constraint into it:

```
def remove_duplicates(string):
    s = set()
    list = []
    for i in string:
        if i not in s:
            s.add(i)
            list.append(i)

    return ''.join(list)

string = "abbbccaaadddd"
print(remove_duplicates(string))
```

This outputs

> abc

What I would want is a function like

```
def remove_duplicates(string, int):
    .....
```

Where if for the same string I input int=2, I want to remove my n characters without removing all the characters. Output should be

> abbccaadd

I'm also concerned about run time and complexity for very large strings, so if my initial approach is bad, please suggest a different approach. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not `abbccaadd`?

Comment: Well the idea is to remove the number of adjacent duplicates based on the integer, and output the remainder

Comment: In this case, shouldn't it be `abcadd`? You should explain in more detail what duplicates exactly should be remoed and why. Do you want to retain `n` chars, or remove `n` chars, or remove the largest multiple of `n` without removing all the chars?

Comment: You're right, I'll fix it in the original post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create group of letters, but compute the length of the groups, maxed out by your parameter.

Then rebuild the groups and join:

```
import itertools

def remove_duplicates(string,maxnb):
    groups = ((k,min(len(list(v)),maxnb)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(string))
    return "".join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v*k for k,v in groups))

string = "abbbccaaadddd"
print(remove_duplicates(string,2))
```

this prints:

```
abbccaadd
```

can be a one-liner as well (cover your eyes!)

```
return "".join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(v*k for k,v in ((k,min(len(list(v)),maxnb)) for k,v in itertools.groupby(string))))
```

not sure about the `min(len(list(v)),maxnb)` repeat value which can be adapted to suit your needs with a modulo (like `len(list(v)) % maxnb`), etc...

Comment: yes, the condition is not very clear. But heavy lifting is done with the grouping & string multiplying. There's "just" the number of repeats to adjust.

Comment: You could also just use `islice` instead of that `min` construct. (I had that as my original answer, then deleted it as it did not match OP's expected output...)

Comment: yes, using `list(x)` just to compute the length is sub-optimal, I know.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understand your question correctly. I *think* that, given `m` repetitions of a character, you want to remove up to `k*n` duplicates such that `k*n < m`.

You could try this, using `groupby`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> string = "abbbccaaadddd"
>>> n = 2
>>> ''.join(c for k, g in groupby(string) for c in k * (len(list(g)) % n or n))
'abccadd'
```

Here, `k * (len(list(g)) % n or n)` means `len(g) % n` repetitions, or `n` if that number is `0`.

---

Oh, you changed it... now my original answer with my "interpretation" of your output actually works. You can use `groupby` together with `islice` to get at most `n` characters from each group of duplicates.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby, islice
>>> string = "abbbccaaadddd"
>>> n = 2
>>> ''.join(c for _, g in groupby(string) for c in islice(g, n))
'abbccaadd'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using `int` as a variable name as it is a python keyword.

Here is a vanilla function that does the job:

```
def deduplicate(string: str, treshold: int) -> str:
    res = ""
    last = ""
    count = 0
    for c in string:
        if c != last:
            count = 0
            res += c
            last = c
        else:
            if count < treshold:
                res += c
                count += 1
    return res
```